# Watch contract event in Ruby

Tags: web3js, ruby

I am building a Ruby on Rails application and I want to subscribe to an event watcher of a published solidity contract in a Ruby task.  I know that if I were programming in Node I could use web3.js to do this.  What is the best way to do this in Ruby??

I am considering making a mini nodejs script that collects the event list and pub-subs it to Ruby using JSON-RPC.  However this seems silly because then I would have Ruby talking to that node script over JSON-RPC which would then be taking to geth over JSON-RPC.  Am I missing something?

Andy